# Syntax error of path in singingconfig.properties in AndroidStudio gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Below is gradle console error statement, signingconfig.properties file, signingconfig.gradle code that reads the file. I believe it is a simple syntax error such as quotes. Could someone correct the syntax in the signingconfig.properties file?

- Where:
  Script '/Users/gregmarsh/AndroidStudioProjects/DanceApps1/WCSVidMet/signingconfig.gradle' line: 23
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null' basedir='/Users/gregmarsh/AndroidStudioProjects/DanceApps1/WCSVidMet'

signingconfig.properties file below

```
debug.store=
release.store=/Users/gregmarsh/AndroidStudioProjects/android.jks
release.storePass=
release.alias=MyAndroidKey
release.pass=
```

signingconfig.gradle code that reads the file below

```
def readPasswordFromConsole(prompt) {
    def c = System.console()
    if(c != null) {
        return new String(System.console().readPassword("\n\$ " + prompt + " "))
    }
    return ""
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        def configPropsFile = file("signingconfig.properties")
        if (configPropsFile.exists()) {
            def props = new Properties()
            props.load(new FileInputStream(configPropsFile))

            debug {
                if(props.debug_store?.trim()) {
                    storeFile file(props.debug_store)
                }
            }

            release {
                storeFile file(props.release_store)
                storePassword(props.release_storePass?.trim() ? props.release_storePass : readPasswordFromConsole("keystore pass:"))
                keyAlias props.release_alias
                keyPassword(props.release_pass?.trim() ? props.release_pass : readPasswordFromConsole("key pass:"))
            }
        } else {
            println "signingconfig.properties file is missing (required for release builds)!"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Android Studio sings? ;-) But seriously, do you have this typo only in your question or also somewhere in the code?

Comment: Typo in the question, I edited sing to sign. It finds the file, but considers a string null or empty. I'm pretty sure the signingconfig.properties needs quotes or a line deleted, or something.

Comment: So your keys are release.store etc. and your code references them as release_store?

Comment: Problem is solved. In the build.com gradle I deleted the line: apply from: "signingconfig.gradle" and removed these files from the project. I just manually type in the release information and password in Android Studio.